# How to export apk in react native for the beta testing in actual device?

Tags: android, react-native

I'am currently new creating react native project. Right now I want to test the sample project to my actual device. After I run the script to the android project and install it to my device. I got an error it says that **Unable to load script. make sure you're either running metro or that your bundle index.android.bundle is packaged correctly for release**

**Goal: To install the release apk to the actual device for beta testing without connecting the usb cable.**

Here is the process that I did:

**1. Creating a script on package.json**

```
"generateAPK": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd .."
```

**2. Here is the logs:**

```
yarn generateAPKyarn run v1.22.17
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..
                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


info Writing bundle output to:, android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 7 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Configure project :app
Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s
321 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 313 up-to-date
✨  Done in 26.02s.
```

**3. After Installing In Actual Device**

[image: Output]

Thank you, I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `npx react-native run-android --variant = release`, and you will find the apk in `android/app/build/outputs`.